# not able to display selected spinner value on a textview using OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I am trying to display the selected value of spinner on a textview but i it shows nothing , i dont understand what the problem is, i am using itemselected listener inside onclick ,i dont understand whats wrong someone please help

```
    package com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.Screens.Extras;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.R;
import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.Screens.AbstractActivity;

public class Settings extends AbstractActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout linearSelectLang,linearSetDefault,linearSelectPanch;
    private TextView txtSelectLang,txtSetDefault,txtSelectPanch;
    private Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        linearSelectLang = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSelectLang);
        linearSetDefault = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSetDefault);
        linearSelectPanch = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSelectPanch);

        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner3);


        txtSelectLang = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectLangtext);
        txtSetDefault = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setdefaulttext);
        txtSelectPanch = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectPanchtext);

        linearSelectLang.setOnClickListener(this);
        linearSetDefault.setOnClickListener(this);
        linearSelectPanch.setOnClickListener(this);
        spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                if(position == 0){
                    txtSelectLang.setText("English");
                }
                else
                {
                    txtSelectLang.setText("Hindi");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.LinearSelectLang:
            {
                spinner1.performClick();




            }
            break;
            case R.id.LinearSetDefault:
            {
                spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        switch(position){
                            case 0:txtSetDefault.setText("Kundli");break;

                            case 1:txtSetDefault.setText("Panchang");break;

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
                spinner2.performClick();

                spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            break;
            case R.id.LinearSelectPanch:
            {
                spinner3.performClick();
                String text = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txtSelectPanch.setText(text);
                spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: it might be because the onItemSelected only will be invoked if the selected item is different from the previousely selected item....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs can you elaborate ?

Comment: for example: item 1 is still selected.now You are selecting item 1 again....then nothing happens. Instead only if You select item 2 in that case will fire the event. But above I see You are setting the visibility directly to GONE....I don´t know if this causes that problem, but delete this and try again...